# React Native Updating State with Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, chart.js

```
   0
```

Hi I'm trying to update the state data value (data:[]) from API. the issue is from the line highlighted this.setState({data.datasets[0].data.data:response.data.rates.AUD})

```
    import React from 'react';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        data: {
            labels:["UK"],
            datasets:[
            {label:"Dev Test",data:[]}
            ]
}}

this.test = this.test.bind(this)
}
 async test() {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
    this.setState({data.datasets[0].data[0]:response.data.rates.AUD})
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
this.setState({data: {
  ...this.state.data,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: this.state.data.datasets[0].label,
      data: response.data.rates.AUD,
    }
  ],
});
```

Comment: Hi I've added this to the code async test() {
 const response = await axios.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
 

this.setState({data: {
  ...this.state.data,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: this.state.data.datasets[0].label,
      data: response.data.rates.AUD,
    }
  ],
});
}

but getting errors 

Failed to compile
./src/App.js
SyntaxError: /Users/maptester/src/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (31:1)

  29 |     }
  30 |   ],
> 31 | });
     |  ^
  32 | }
  33 | 
  34 |

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to update a value for a property inside an object and you have to do it for the whole `data` property:

```js
this.setState({data: {
  ...this.state.data,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: this.state.data.datasets[0].label,
      data: response.data.rates.AUD,
    }
  ],
});
```

I don't actually think this code I wrote is correct because I don't understand the structure of your data, but the idea is that you have to update the whole `data` state all together, keeping old data you want to keep and updating new data. You can't update directly a property in an array in an object. You can update separately first level properties though. Check this: https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60