# React Native Updating State with this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

Hi I'm trying to update the state data value (`data:[]`) from API. the issue is from the line highlighted:

```
this.setState({data.datasets[0].data.data:response.data.rates.AUD})
```

```
import React from 'react'; import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import axios from 'axios';
 
class App extends React.Component {
 
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           data: {
               labels:["UK"],
               datasets:[
                 {label:"Dev Test",data:[]}
                ] }}
    
    this.test = this.test.bind(this) }  
    async test() {
        const response = await axios.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
        this.setState({data.datasets[0].data[0]:response.data.rates.AUD})
    }
```

Comment: can you make a schema from your json data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Updating State with Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65562408/react-native-updating-state-with-api)

Comment: @Hardik3296 nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please check below code.

```
this.setState((prev) => {
  prev.data.datasets[0].data[0] = response.data.rates.AUD;
  return {
    ...prev
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setState like this :

```
this.setState((prev) => {
  prev.data.datasets[0].data[0] = response.data.rates.AUD;
  return {
    ...prev
  };
});
```

Comment: thank you it works but when i click on the button to activate the this.setState

This error appears:
TypeError: data.datasets.map is not a function

Comment: Ill fix this just a second.